# PHP 5.6 ZTS and PHP 7 ZTS MongoDB Driver issue

Tags: php, mongodb, pthreads, php-5.6, zts

I had a major problem with choice of PHP and MongoDB versions.

I have a project developed in PHP5.6 with PHP 5 MongoDB Driver and I am willing to use PHP with ZTS and pThreads for parallel execution. Unfortunately when I compile PHP with ZTS and pthreads compiler gives me error while setting up PHP

```
/usr/src/php-5.6.12/meta_ccld -DZEND_ENABLE_STATIC_TSRMLS_CACHE=1 -Iext/pthreads/ -I/usr/src/php-5.6.12/ext/pthreads/ -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/usr/src/php-5.6.12/include -I/usr/src/php-5.6.12/main -I/usr/src/php-5.6.12 -I/usr/src/php-5.6.12/ext/date/lib -I/usr/src/php-5.6.12/ext/ereg/regex -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/src/php-5.6.12/ext/mbstring/oniguruma -I/usr/src/php-5.6.12/ext/mbstring/libmbfl -I/usr/src/php-5.6.12/ext/mbstring/libmbfl/mbfl -I/usr/src/php-5.6.12/ext/sqlite3/libsqlite -I/usr/src/php-5.6.12/ext/pthreads -I/usr/src/php-5.6.12/ext/zip/lib -I/usr/src/php-5.6.12/TSRM -I/usr/src/php-5.6.12/Zend -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/include -g -fvisibility=hidden -pthread - O0 -Wall -DZTS -c /usr/src/php-5.6.12/ext/pthreads/php_pthreads.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o ext/pthreads/.libs/php_pthreads.o
```

> In file included from
>   /usr/src/php-5.6.12/ext/pthreads/php_pthreads.c:22:0:
>
> ext/pthreads/src/pthreads.h:72:35: fatal error:
>   Zend/zend_inheritance.h: No such file or directory
>    #include 
>    ^
>   compilation terminated.
>   make: *** [ext/pthreads/php_pthreads.lo] Error 1

Now, one may thing why I am sticking to PHP5, Its clearly becuase of MongoDB driver of php5. PHP7 with ZTS works perfectly but again I canot connect MongoDB because php7 have different mongoDB driver.

Please guide me whether updating code to PHP7 Mongo is just a solution left with me ? or is there any workaround ?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by configuring the PHP ZTS 5.5.8 with CentOS 6.5

My problem was I was installing pthreads v3 with php 5.x but unfortunately it is not supported. I also tried pthreads v2 with ubuntu but somehow it wont work so i changed destro and it works perfectly now.

Hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

In folder pthreads run:

```
git checkout PHP5
```

I installed PHP5 with ZTS:

```
mkdir /usr/local/src/
wget http://uk1.php.net/get/php-5.6.12.tar.gz/from/this/mirror -O php.tar.gz
tar xzvf php.tar.gz
cd php-5.6.12/ext
git clone https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads.git
cd pthreads
git checkout PHP5
```